# EmberJs: wrapping Bootstrap components (timepicker)

Tags: ember.js

I'm already using the ember-bootstrap plugin (great job !!)
But I need to add a time picker (https://github.com/jdewit/bootstrap-timepicker) to this Bootstrap plugin.
I'm not an EmberJs expert yet... 
Can someone provide me some help to wrap this time picker with ember-bootstrap ?

**Update:**
I have found this solution without ember-bootstrap plugin and it works.
Is it the right way to process ?

```
Bootstrap.TimePicker = Em.ContainerView.create({
  classNames: 'input-append bootstrap-timepicker-component',
  childViews: ['inputView', 'iconView'],
  inputView: Em.TextField.create({
    type: 'text',
    valueBinding: 'App.PassController.storeCard.relevantDate',
    classNames: 'timepicker-default input-small'
  }),
  iconView: Em.View.create({
    tagName: 'span',
    classNames: 'add-on',
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('<i class="icon-time"></i>')
  }),
  didInsertElement: function() {
    $('.timepicker-default').timepicker({showSeconds: true, defaultTime: 'value'});
  }
}).append();
```

Comment: I just noticed you updated the question. Yeah, I'd say this is the way to do it

Comment: Just a quick note, do `this.$('.timepicker-default').timepicker()` so it looks for that element within your view and not all other elements (in case you have more than one element with that class, so it doesn't re-create the picker for another element)

Comment: You basically have it, although it's probably more idiomatic Ember to use a plain `Ember.View` and add those child elements in the template itself. Needing to use `Ember.ContainerView` directly is rare.

Comment: Unrelated to main question though: the use of global paths like `'App.PassController.storeCard.relevantDate'` should jump out as a code smell. It probably means you're organizing the application is an incorrect way. Views access properties from their controller 99.99994% of the time.

Comment: @TrekGlowacki in that case, how should the binding be declared? `controller.storeCard.relevantDate`?

Comment: No need to use `controller`. The context of a template already is `controller`: https://gist.github.com/4370723

Comment: @Trek: 1. Is is not possible to embed the: <span class='add-on'><i class="icon-time"></i></span> in the javascript part ? 2. You have missed to include the classNames: 'input-append bootstrap-timepicker-component' div wrapper ?

Comment: @fvisticot 1. Yes, but it's atypical Ember 2. I was demonstrating the default rendering context of a template, not providing a complete example.